# Laravel : $stg is undefined

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

The problem is an undefined variable `stg` in the view. My controller:

```
public function editstg($id)
{
  $stg= Stgeffectue::find($id);
  return view('frontend.editstage',['stg'=>$stg]);
} 

public function updatestg(Request $request, $id)
{
  $stg = Stgeffectue::find($id);

  $stg->nom_stg=$request->input('nom_stg');
  $stg->lieu_stg=$request->input('lieu_stg');
  $stg->details_stg=$request->input('details_stg');

  $stg->save();

  return redirect('stage_effectues');
}
```

and this is my view code

```html
<form action=" {{ action('StgeffectueController@updatestg', $stg->id) }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enregistrer" class="form-control btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-primary">
    <label class="col-form-label col-md-4">Nom Stage :</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nom_stg" value="{{ $stg->nom_stg}}" />
```

The route code:

```
Route::get('/editstage/{id}','StgeffectueController@editstg');
Route::put('/editstage/{id}','StgeffectueController@updatestg');
```

Comment: change the `$stg= Stgeffectue::find($id);` to `$stg= Stgeffectue::findOrFail($id);`

Comment: i change it but it doesn't work still an undifined variable

Answer (score 0):

try to return view like this

```
return view('frontend.editstage')->with(compact('stg'));
```

Comment: i try it but it doesn't change anything still an undifined variable

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you are getting the error due to `$stg = Stgeffectue::find($id);` returning `null` in the `editstg` function.

You will get null when **no record** with the particular `id` is present in the database.

Try changing that line to

```
$stg= Stgeffectue::findOrFail($id);
```

(as suggested by N69S).